# Can I use the same JavaScript Function on multiple Div's?

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar

I'm new to javascript and I need to make circle progress that shows percentage with animated bar
luckily I have done it but the problem is I want to make 5 or more of the same circle with the different percentages  and **I need to start on page load not by click **
So how to call the function on more than one div so that the circles appears with different percentages at the same time

Here's my JS code

```js
let firstLayer = document.querySelector('.cardHolder'),
  secondLayer = document.querySelector('.skillSecond'),
  startValue = 0,
  endValue = 50,
  duration = 20;

let progress = setInterval(() => {
  startValue++
  secondLayer.textContent = `${startValue}%`
  firstLayer.style.background = `conic-gradient(rgb(15, 176, 6) ${startValue * 3.6}deg, rgb(193, 193, 193) 0deg)`
  if (startValue == endValue) {
    clearInterval(progress)
  }
}, duration);
```

```css
.cardHolder {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: conic-gradient(rgb(15, 176, 6) 3.6deg, rgb(193, 193, 193) 0deg);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.skillFirst {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #90697a;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.skillSecond {
  font-family: 'Montserrat Subrayada', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cardHolder">
  <div class="skillFirst">
    <div class="skillSecond">
      <span class="skillContent"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i came up with. Basically it works by making an array of objects containing the specifications for each individual progressbar. Then loop over the specifications and start every Interval.

```js
let progression = [
                    {
                      progressBarId: "first",
                      progressBarLabelId: "first_label",
                      startValue: 0,
                      endValue: 50,
                      duration: 20
                    },
                    {
                      progressBarId: "second",
                      progressBarLabelId: "second_label",
                      startValue: 10,
                      endValue: 100,
                      duration: 10
                    },
                    {
                      progressBarId: "third",
                      progressBarLabelId: "third_label",
                      startValue: 50,
                      endValue: 80,
                      duration: 20
                    }
                  ];
                  
window.onload = function() {

  for(var i = 0; i < progression.length; i++) {
    let firstLayer = document.getElementById(progression[i].progressBarId),
    secondLayer = document.getElementById(progression[i].progressBarLabelId),
    startValue = progression[i].startValue,
    endValue = progression[i].endValue,
    duration = progression[i].duration;
  
  
    let progress = setInterval(() => {
      startValue++
      secondLayer.textContent = `${startValue}%`
      firstLayer.style.background = `conic-gradient(rgb(15, 176, 6) ${startValue * 3.6}deg, rgb(193, 193, 193) 0deg)`
      if (startValue == endValue) {
        clearInterval(progress)
      }
    }, duration);

  }


}
```

```css
.cardHolder {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: conic-gradient(rgb(15, 176, 6) 3.6deg, rgb(193, 193, 193) 0deg);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.skillFirst {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #90697a;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.skillSecond {
  font-family: 'Montserrat Subrayada', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cardHolder" id="first">
  <div class="skillFirst">
    <div class="skillSecond" id="first_label">
      <span class="skillContent" ></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="cardHolder" id="second">
  <div class="skillFirst">
    <div class="skillSecond" id="second_label">
      <span class="skillContent" ></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="cardHolder" id="third">
  <div class="skillFirst">
    <div class="skillSecond" id="third_label">
      <span class="skillContent" ></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps, if not, please comment!

Comment: thanks so much for your replay,  Apparently  you made it as oop right ??
then you put it in array then loop the array with the the oop values ,then execute the function right ???

Comment: That is exactly what is happening yes.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer, it will help others in the future @A.rahmanShoukry

Comment: done  it for sure ,vthanks so much again